# Is it possible to output the percentage of scenarios run, with each scenario?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In Cucumber on Ruby, when running big features, I would like to see how far I already am; one useful info would be something like "Scenario 20 of 100" or "30% of scenarios done", printed together with the scenario titles.

This would be easy to implement myself in a hook if there was a way to get said information (i.e. the position of the current scenario in the current feature file; plus the total number of scenarios in the same file). Is this possible somehow? I am aware that there is the cucumber-ruby API documentation, but it is very unclear to me how to access that stuff from outside of the cucumber core implementation (i.e., from "user-land").

Comment: A google search turned up [this](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Progress_Bars) in a small fraction of a second. Looks like there's a clear winner, but without seeing **your** code it's pretty hard for anybody to say how any of these would slide into your codebase.

Comment: @pjs, thanks for googling for me, but those gems you found have little to do with the question. The question is not about how to render a progress bar, but how to hook into cucumber to figure out the "input" for said progress bar (or in my case, I do not need nor want any fancy display, a simple percentage number would be more than sufficient).